Converting NetCDF to CSV timeseries using R
I have a code written in R that extracts data from an NC file to compute a time series for a specific location using latitude and longitude. However, the file only outputs three values instead of the entire date timeline. Why is this happening?
Additionally, I received an error message.
`x` must not contain list or matrix columns:✖ invalid columns at index(s): 1
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

How can I fix this?
install.packages("ncdf4")
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("lubridate")

library(ncdf4)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Step 1: Define the folder containing NetCDF files and output path
folder_path <- "C:/Users/WINDOWS 10/Downloads/MSWEP/Daily"
output_csv <- "C:/Users/WINDOWS 10/Downloads/Full_Precipitation_Timeseries2.csv"

# Define the target latitude and longitude
target_lat <- 14.8903
target_lon <- -19.2321

# Initialize an empty data frame to store the results
all_time_series <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(character()), Precipitation = numeric())

# Step 2: Process each NetCDF file in the folder
nc_files <- list.files(folder_path, pattern = "\\.nc$", full.names = TRUE)

for (file in nc_files) {
  cat("\nProcessing file:", file, "\n")
  
  # Open the NetCDF file
  nc <- nc_open(file)
  
  # Extract latitude, longitude, and time variables
  latitudes <- ncvar_get(nc, "lat")  # Adjust "lat" if variable name differs
  longitudes <- ncvar_get(nc, "lon")  # Adjust "lon" if variable name differs
  time <- ncvar_get(nc, "time")  # Adjust "time" if variable name differs
  
  # Convert time to dates
  time_units <- ncatt_get(nc, "time", "units")$value
  cat("Time units:", time_units, "\n")
  
  time_origin <- strsplit(time_units, "since ")[[1]][2]
  if (!is.null(time_origin)) {
    dates <- as.Date(time, origin = time_origin)
    cat("Sample dates:", head(dates), "\n")
  } else {
    cat("Warning: Time origin not found in file:", file, "\n")
    nc_close(nc)
    next
  }
  
  # Enforce `dates` as a Date vector
  dates <- as.Date(dates)
  
  # Find the nearest grid point indices for target lat/lon
  lat_idx <- which.min(abs(latitudes - target_lat))
  lon_idx <- which.min(abs(longitudes - target_lon))
  cat("Latitude index:", lat_idx, "Longitude index:", lon_idx, "\n")
  
  # Extract precipitation data for all available time points
  precip_subset <- ncvar_get(nc, "precipitation", 
                             start = c(lon_idx, lat_idx, 1), 
                             count = c(1, 1, -1))  # Adjust count if needed
  
  # Ensure `precip_subset` is a numeric vector
  precip_subset <- as.vector(precip_subset)
  
  # Debugging: Check dimensions and content of precipitation data
  cat("Length of precip_subset:", length(precip_subset), "\n")
  if (length(precip_subset) > 0) {
    cat("Sample precipitation data:", head(precip_subset), "\n")
  } else {
    cat("Warning: Empty precipitation data for file:", file, "\n")
    nc_close(nc)
    next
  }
  
  # Combine dates and precipitation into a data frame
  file_time_series <- data.frame(Date = dates, Precipitation = precip_subset)
  
  # Ensure Date is consistently a Date type
  file_time_series$Date <- as.Date(file_time_series$Date)
  
  # Append to the overall time series
  all_time_series <- bind_rows(all_time_series, file_time_series)
  
  # Close the NetCDF file
  nc_close(nc)
}

# Debugging: Check the final combined time series
cat("\nFinal time series preview:\n")
print(head(all_time_series))

# Step 3: Save the combined time series to a CSV file
if (nrow(all_time_series) > 0) {
  write_csv(all_time_series, output_csv)
  cat("Precipitation time series saved to:", output_csv, "\n")
} else {
  cat("No valid data extracted. CSV file was not created.\n")
}


Did you run the trace? What does that contain?

Impossible to really help without your data. You are looping over NC files? How many? Is the error message when processing one of them or when you combine all of them? Rewrite the code in the loop as a function that works on one file and test on each file.

The file contains over 200 NC files. The error message appears after processing the whole dataset, and when the data is to be exported to CSV, an error comes up. I have shared a link to the data https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/163d9mrd979gN6ZikFqMYLKKJjBgkDPyq?usp=drive_link

The error occurs with fewer files, so you only needed to share three of them which would save us a lot of downloads. Minimise the work of people who are helping you!

For some reason, when using dplyr::bind_rows to build your data frame, you end up with a dataframe that disagrees with write_csv:
> readr::write_csv(all_time_series,"d.csv")
Error in `cli_block()`:
! `x` must not contain list or matrix columns:
✖ invalid columns at index(s): 1
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

something to do with the dimension of the date column. Simplest fix is:

remove library(tidyverse) and never type that again. If you want to use functions from the tidyverse collection of packages only attach the components you need, eg library(ggplot2) or library(dplyr), or prefix the function calls like dplyr::bind_rows.
remove library(lubridate) because your script doesn't use it
replace bind_rows with rbind
replace write_csv with write.csv. You might want to add some extra parameters to that to remove row labels, or change the quotes or separator.

Now your script actually works, runs lighter and possibly faster (because you have removed dependencies).
I don't know the underlying reason why it breaks with bind_rows and write_csv (I have an idea but no enthusiasm to dig into fixing it when the real fix is "use the corresponding base R functions").
Here's what I get from your NCDF files:
> prec = read.csv("./Full_Precipitation_Timeseries2.csv")
> plot(as.Date(prec$Date), prec$Precipitation,type="l")


